# Why Nginx Mail Module encoded '%' to %25 in Auth-Pass header?

Tags: nginx, email

I do the test with the special character password below

```
~`!@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|\/:;"'<>,.?
```

And I realised nginx mail module encoded the `%` to `%25`, but the rest of the special character are fine, is it pre encoded from mail client level ?

```
 *3653 http header: "Auth-Pass: ~`!@#$%25^&*()-_+={}[]|\/:;<>,.?" 
 *3653 http proxy header: "Auth-Pass: ~`!@#$%25^&*()-_+={}[]|\/:;<>,.?"
```

Comment: What is your nginx configuration?

Comment: I am follow [this at the bottom's complete example](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/mail-proxy/mail-proxy/). But normally http call header will not encoding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while,

I decided to research this module, just realize it's only supports PLAIN_TEXT at the moment.

I will just enabled PLAIN_TEXT authentication will do the trick.

Comment: @WoomMonika in case you only have one Mail Server, you can just proxy instead to intercept the connection

Comment: I have 4 mail servers. But i managed to handle just passing authentication will do